# Container insites parsing with regex in Azure Kubernetes logs

Tags: regex, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I have the following regex

((([.+])?( INFO saml20.implementation.common.SAMLUtil - Success: Successful sign on: ))|(INFO - SAML_SSO: Success: Successful sign on: ))(.+)

Which is good at matching

[abc1521269039-3709] INFO saml20.implementation.common.SAMLUtil - Success: Successful sign on: fred@flintstone.com
or
INFO - SAML_SSO: Success: Successful sign on: fred@flintstone.com

However when I try to add it to my insites query

ContainerInventory
| join (
ContainerLog
| where LogEntry contains "Successful sign on"
| project LogonTime=TimeGenerated, LogEntry, ContainerID
) on ContainerID
| project LogonTime, LogEntry, Image
| extend LogEntry = extract("((([.+])?( INFO saml20.implementation.common.SAMLUtil - Success: Successful sign on: ))|(INFO - SAML_SSO: Success: Successful sign on: ))(.+)",1,LogEntry)
| extend New_Column = strcat(LogEntry, Image)
| order by New_Column
| distinct New_Column

It fails on the extract line.

Looking for a second set of eyes on someone who may see what I have messed up.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This must have been a glitch with Azure. It works today.

Thanks,